# On django admin side Get field data from Api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

On my application on front client side I am getting City field data from a Api using this  `"http://gd.geobytes.com/GetCityDetails?callback=?&fqcn="+cityfqcn`  in ajax call.

Now I want to do same thing in this field on admin side ?  As far I tried to field I didn't get any helpful thing. your any help would be highly appreciated . thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

My model.py is

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Please show the models.

Comment: @DarkOrb  updated kindly check

Comment: @DarkOrb is it possible ?

Comment: Yes you can easily inject custom html and js in admin panel, I wanted create small snippet for you but couldn't understand your usecase

Comment: @DarkOrb  I want that admin can select a city in dropdown and that dropdown data will be coming from this api I mentioned . And the country using this api get automatically. So my use case is If Admin write M  it will show all cities starting from M like munich  and other and country name will be retrived on city selection .

Comment: @DarkOrb kindly ask If any thing is not clear.

Comment: @DarkOrb if my case is difficult to understand you can give any example to get api data in dropdown in any field of django admin.